# @Names disappearing in Comments, Why?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

In [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16240/is-my-sparkfun-rs232-shifter-smd-faulty) I was trying to write this comment:

> @RichardFreedman @MattJenkins @vicatcu
>   please check my edit to the question
>   and see if I have understood
>   correctly. Thanks!

No matter how many times I tried to edit or repost it always removes "@RichardFreedman". Why is it doing this? Does it have something to do with him being the OP?

Comment: It worked for me when I tried it.

Comment: But the "@Kellenjb" was removed from the previous comment too! :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@lerting the post owner in a comment is not necessary. If comments are only between you and the post-owner, and nobody else is commenting, then an @lert to the post owner at the beginning of a comment will be removed.

You can only notify one person in a comment.  So in your example, you'd be notifying the post owner, except that the post owner is always notified of a comment on one of their posts without being named in it.  Matt and vicatcu would not receive a notification.  By removing the post owner from the beginning of a comment, we're freeing up a notification slot to Matt.  Note that vicatcu still will not be notified.

Comment: I am not sure what other users think of this, but it seems very annoying to me. It seems like the amount of work done to realize that the @lerting was to the post owner and then editing the comment could just as easily have gone to looking at @lerting for multiple people in one post.

Comment: I am also not a big fan of a website automatically changing the content of my post, especially with out alerting me first, even when it is something as minor as removing an @name.

Comment: Like I commented under the question, I tried to comment under the question @Kellenjb mentioned, with exactly the same text, and it didn't remove "@RichardFreeman". I have the impression that this may be a bug.

Comment: @stevenvh, please read my post more closely.  It only happens when only one person besides the post owner is involved in the comments.  It is just noise at that point, but when someone else gets involved, the text isn't messed with for clarity.

Comment: @Rebecca Chernoff In my situation removing the @RichardFreeman hurt the clarity of my post as it made it seem like I didn't care for him to edit his own post. I don't understand how that is noise at all.

Comment: i can confirm, i did not recieve a notification... unfortunate limitation

Comment: @Vicatcu I guess in the future I will just need to make several comments, each referencing different people. :-)

Comment: @Rebecca Was this a newly implemented feature? I never remember running across this before and it has managed to catching me twice in 1 day. I am pretty sure I am so used to doing it I don't even think about it.

Comment: I tend to always type "@first last" and the site strips off the @first and leaves just the last name.

Comment: @Kellenjb, yes it is new, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97098/140548 for more details.

Comment: I agree that @lerting the post author is noise and removing it makes sense since putting the @alert there is pointless in the first place. However, I think it would be useful if a comment can alert multiple people that are not post owners. Of course that's easy for me to say since I don't have to modify the code to do that.